# When you type "if" no prompt anymore

Tags: terminal, kali-linux

The prompt is gone if you type `if` for `ifconfig`. That shouldn't happen.

```
┌──(rootkali)-[~] 
└─#

┌──(rootkali)-[~] 
└─# if
if> exit
if> ifconfig
if> iwconfig
if> clear
if>
```

Answer (score 7):

The shell is waiting for you to complete [the `if` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_07). You can return to the “normal” prompt by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> or entering `fi` (which will abort with a syntax error).

Comment: As it looks like the shell is `zsh`, entering `(:):` or `{} :` would also return to a normal prompt as it would finish those short forms of the `if` statement: `if (:):` being short for `if ( : ); then :; fi`

Comment: Yes, there are many ways of returning to the main prompt. I wasn’t planning on providing an exhaustive list, just a couple of hopefully easy-to-remember fixes ;-). Incidentally, Ctrl-D works on bash but not zsh, which is why I omitted that solution.

Answer (score 2):

`if` starts if-conditional block in shell (the scripting language bash/zsh/dash/ksh...). It expects the if condition.

It can be stopped by `ctrl`+`c` (SIGINT) or `fi` (end of if-block).

Answer (score 1):

Already explained in the other answer, how to exit the `if-statement`.

To get the zsh competition, you need to press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Here is an example:

Type `if` then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> you will get:

```
~if 
if     ifconfig  ifdown    ifquery   ifup      ifuse
```

To get `ifconfig` command, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.